# SOAP over non-HTTP protocol

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I just wondered if there are any libraries in Java or any other language implementing SOAP over protocol that is not HTTP? I've heard that some project had implemented SOAP over SMTP. Are there any other experiences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main features of SOAP 1.2 was the removal of the dependency on HTTP, allowing other transports to be used.

As for java implementations, [Spring WebServices](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/) supports SOAP 1.2 over HTTP, JMS and SMTP. See  section 5.3 of [the docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

[This may be a good starting point](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-pyth12.html). I know it's from 2003 but seems to be dead on the mark in regards to what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Axis 1.4 has transport handlers not just for HTTP, but also for [JMS](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/transport/jms/JMSTransport.html) and [SMTP/POP3](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/apiDocs/org/apache/axis/transport/mail/MailTransport.html). If you look carefully, the Mail protocol is not recommended for production.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html) with [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org) as transport.
Such approach will give you good abstraction from transport layer. For example, my app allow soap calls via netty/TCP, JMS queue, jetty/HTTP and even netty/udp.